# Android 12 Splash screen icon

Tags: android, android-splashscreen

I want to use new Android 12 API for Splash Screen, but if I use my `drawable` icon inside theme for parameter `windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon`, its stretched. How can I adjust size of that icon?
My icon is not vector. I have to use png file.

Answer (score 7):

Likely, you have to follow the [Splash Screen dimensions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen#splash_screen_dimensions).
Google says:

- App icon with an icon background: This should be 240×240 dp, and fit within a circle of 160 dp in diameter.
- App icon without an icon background: This should be 288×288 dp, and fit within a circle of 192 dp in diameter.

[image]

Comment: How to generate these icons? I mean I have an icon, but how to set its width and height according to these guidelines?

Comment: @TalhaAkbar You can use vector editing software, like Figma for example.

Comment: Why does the documentation of icons always have extra space for the icons, that has nothing in it?

Comment: @RisalFajarAmiyardi But there isn't a dp measurement. I use inskcape.

Comment: @TalhaAkbar were you able to do this,how?

Comment: @HasIEluS I created a <layer-list> and added the drawable and set it's size. It wasn't a good solution though.

Answer (score -1):

create 2 values directory

in values-v31

```
<style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/color_121326
    </item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/SplashScreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">
        @drawable/ic_splash_center
    </item>
    <item name="splashScreenIconSize">@dimen/dp_100</item>
</style>
```

and in values-v33

```
<style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground">@color/color_121326
    </item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/SplashScreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">
        @drawable/drawable_splash
    </item>
    <item name="splashScreenIconSize">@dimen/dp_100</item>
</style>
```

in drawable_splash

```
<item
    android:width="@dimen/dp_100"
    android:height="@dimen/dp_100"
    android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_splash_center" />
</item>
```

i find it works to resize icon above api33